# Storing the keysets from a JPQL query result in a java list

Tags: java, jpql

I was successfully able to execute a jpql query and print the result which is stored in a `queryResults` variable. What I want to achieve next is storing just the IDs (primary key column) in a list without the date (value), but I am not too sure if this is possible; perhaps using something like a java map. Is it possible? If yes, how can this be easily achieved?

```
  private static final TestDao Test_DAO = new TestDao();

 @Test
 public void testById() {
List<TestEntity> queryResults = TEST_DAO.findById(""); //The record from the sql query is stored in queryResults and findById("") is the method that executes the query in a TestDao class and it is called here

for (TestEntity qResult: queryResults) { // looping through the query result to print the rows
System.out.println(qResult.getId());
System.out.println(qResult.getDate());
}

System.out.println("This is the sql result " + queryResults );
       
}

Output:
This is the result [TestEntity(id=101, date=2020-01-19 15:12:32.447), TestEntity(id=102, date=2020-09-01 11:04:10.0)]// I want to get the IDs 101 and 102 and store in a list without the Dates
```

I tried using a `map` this way:

`Map<Integer, Timestamp> map= (Map<Integer, Timestamp>) queryResults.get(0);` but I got an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: TestEntity cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

Comment: You have declared your DAO object as static - No clue why !
The method name is - findById but it apparently returns a list. Key should be unique in the table. And it takes in an empty String as param !!
And ofcourse you getting an exception. queryResults.get(0) returns a TestEntity Object and you are asking Java to cast it to Map !

Comment: I am answering based on the comment on the last line. Actually I am not answering, I am helping you to answer yourself. You are doing this to get the id and print it: System.out.println(qResult.getId());    So you already have the id, each iteration you have one id. Can you not add it to a list ???

Comment: queryResults is already a list of keys and values, but I want a list of just the keys. Please demonstrate how you think it can be achieved. How do I add just the Ids to a list? Thanks

Comment: **queryResults is already a list of keys and values** - this is not correct. queryResults is a **List of TestEntity**

Comment: **List<TestEntity> queryResults = TEST_DAO.findById("")** You are fetching a list of TestEntity. Then you looping over the list to extract the Id and Date and print it. If you can do that, can you not add these ids to a list and get the List of Ids ?

Comment: Show me how, if you know

Comment: You can define a List outside the forloop and keep on adding the Ids to the list inside the for Loop. Another way of doing it is using [JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html). you can define a query like - Select te.id from TestEntity te and use the EntityManager to get back a list of List of Ids, make sure to get the data in the correct type List<Whatever type your Ids are>

Comment: To make things easier, can you use my code to create your suggestions in the provided answer box and then I can accept the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some points before the implementation.

1. Why are you defining DAO as static? I think this is a bad implementation unless I am missing a particular reason you declared it static. You should define this as a member variable and not a static member
2. The naming of the method - `findById()` translated in English is - find Something by this Id, but you are fetching a list of Records, so naming is not correct.
3. Point 2 becomes invalid if *ID* property is not a Primary Key in your table, then it makes sense, but still naming is bad. Id is something we use to define Primary Key in the Database and should be and will be unique. But your comments suggest that ID is unique and the Primary Key. So read about how Databases work
4. And even if not unique, if you pass an Id to find some records, why will get different ids in the Records !!!

About implementation:

1. Changing in your existing code:

```java
private TestDao Test_DAO = new TestDao();

@Test
public void testById() {
  List<TestEntity> queryResults = TEST_DAO.findById("");
  List<Long> listOfIds = new ArrayList<>(); // Assuming Id is Long type, same logic for any type
  for (TestEntity qResult: queryResults) {
    System.out.println(qResult.getId());
    listOfIds.add(qResult.getId());   // Just add it to the list
    System.out.println(qResult.getDate());
  }
       
}
```

In case you want to be efficient with the query:
You can use [JPQL](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_04/ejb3_langref.html) and [hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html)

You can then write a query like:

```java
String query = "select te.id from TestEntity te";
// Create the TypedQuery using EntityManager and then get ResultSet back
List<Long> ids = query.getResultList();
```

3. In case of using Spring-Data-Jpa, you can define the repository and define the method and pass the query with @Query annotation. [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/springdata/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)

Comment: Let me ask this. The Date is a timestamp. If say I want to add 10 minutes to the timestamp, what is the cleanest way to achieve this? If you can update your answer by adding your suggestion, it will be greatly appreciated

Comment: There are different ways to do it, depends on what Data Type you using. Check out the documentation, these are straightforward questions and I want you to get habituated with the documents and how to use it. [Java 8 Time Api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)